# How should I program this in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Here's what I am trying to do: The user enters a string. The string contains 2 parts and will look like this:

```
{EventClass: someMethod=>arg1, arg2, arg3....}, {Action: someMethod=>arg1, arg2, arg3....}
```

A concrete example of this would be:

```
{TwitterEvent: newTweet=>arg1, arg2, arg3....}, {PersistenceAction: saveToHardDrive=>arg1 arg2...}
```

Then I will parse this string, instantiate an instance of `TwitterEvent`, call that method on it. Then do the same thing for `PersistenceAction`

What the best "design" for this type of application? How would I dynamically instantiate classes from parsed string and then call method? And potentially, the method will have arguments? How would I detect/handle errors?

Comment: Be easier with a slightly different input format, like, say, a legal hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get class object from name string:

```
 Kernel.const_get('TwitterEvent')
```

Invoke arbitrary method on object:

```
 event.send(:new_tweet)
```

The rest is up to you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [respond_to? and send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html) .  Send allows you to invoke a method using a symbol.  You can use to_sym to convert a string to a symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
str = "{TwitterEvent: newTweet=>arg1, arg2, arg3}, {PersistenceAction: saveToHardDrive=>arg1, arg2}"

regexp = /^{(\w+):\s*(\w+)=>([^}]+)},\s*{(\w+):\s*(\w+)=>([^}]+)}$/

regexp.match(str).to_a[1..-1].each_slice(3) do |s|
  # s[0] .. class name
  # s[1] .. class method
  # s[2] .. method parameters as a single string
  # do something similar to Sergio Tulentsev suggestion
end
```